# Email Automation Script Variable Output inside Body

Tags: shell, unix

I am looking to add dynamic values inside the email message body. Further, I would like to output my subject as dynamic as well having multiple values. Is there a simpler way to code this?

```
#variables
var7=$1
var=$2
var0=$3
var1=$4
var2=$5
var3=$6
var4=$7
subject="$8"" ""$9"" ""$10"


echo "Hi

Greetings!

$var7 $var
$var1 $var2
$var3 $var4


Greetings! $ticketnumber

Kind regards,
" | mail -s $subject name@test.com -- -f name@test.com
```

Regards,

Chris

Comment: use loops ? Literally, you can add a loop to take the first $1..$7 into one array. Also, as a side note, please improve the variable names.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: CentOS release 4.8 (Final)

Comment: I am using Bash